# TypeError: '_TupleWrapper' object is not callable when I run the object detection model ssd

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, vgg-net

I build my own vgg network 
then I create the dataset then run the train

```
def run_train(dataset, num_epochs=2):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    model = VGGBase()

    for _ in tf.data.Dataset.range(num_epochs):
        for image,target in dataset: # (batch_size (N), 300, 300, 3)
            print(type(image), type(target))
```

this type is

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'>
```

Then I got the following error on

> File "/home/jake/Gits/ssd_tensorflow/model.py", line 56, in call
>       x = self.conv1_1(x)# (N, 64, 300, 300) TypeError: '_TupleWrapper' object is not callable
>
> class  VGGBase(Model):
>       def **init**(self):
>           super(VGGBase,self).**init**()
>           self.padding_1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1))  # put this before your conv layer
>           self.conv1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3,padding='same',strides=1, activation='relu'),
>           self.conv1_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding='same',strides=1,activation='relu'),
>           self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
>
> ```
>     self.conv2_1  =  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding='same',strides= 1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv2_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3,padding='same',strides= 1,activation='relu'),
>     self.pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
>
>     self.conv3_1 =  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same',strides= 1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv3_2 =  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same',strides= 1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv3_3 =  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same',strides= 1,activation='relu'),
>     self.pool3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
>
>     self.conv4_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv4_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv4_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.pool4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
>
>     self.conv5_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv5_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.conv5_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=1,activation='relu'),
>     self.pool5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
>
>     self.padding6 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(6, 6))  # put this before your conv layer
>     self.conv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=3, padding='same',dilation_rate=6,activation='relu') # atrous convolution
>     self.conv7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=1,activation='relu')
>     #self.load_weights()
> def call(self,x):
>     x = self.padding_1(x)
>     x = self.conv1_1(x)# (N, 64, 300, 300)
>     x = self.conv1_2(x)# (N, 64, 300, 300)
>     x = self.pool1(x) # (N, 64, 150, 150)
>
>     x = self.conv2_1(x) # (N, 128, 150, 150)
>     x = self.conv2_2(x) # (N, 128, 150, 150)
>     x = self.pool2(x)# (N, 128, 75, 75)
>
>     x = self.conv3_1(x) # (N, 256, 75, 75)
>     x = self.conv3_2(x)# (N, 256, 75, 75)
>     x = self.conv3_3(x)# (N, 256, 75, 75)
>     x = self.pool3(x) #(N, 256, 38, 38), it would have been 37 if not for ceil_mode = True
>
>     x = self.conv4_1(x)# (N, 512, 38, 38)
>     x = self.conv4_2(x)# (N, 512, 38, 38)
>     x = self.conv4_3(x)# (N, 512, 38, 38)
>     conv4_3_feats = x# (N, 512, 38, 38)
>     x = self.pool4(x)# (N, 512, 19, 19)
>
>     x = self.conv5_1(x) # (N, 512, 19, 19)
>     x = self.conv5_2(x) # (N, 512, 19, 19)
>     x = self.conv5_3(x) # (N, 512, 19, 19)
>     x = self.pool5(x) # (N, 512, 19, 19), pool5 does not reduce dimensions
>
>     x = self.padding6(x)
>     x = self.conv6(x) # (N, 1024, 19, 19)
>     x = self.conv7(x) # (N, 1024, 19, 19)
>     conv7_feats = x
>
>     return conv4_3_feats, conv7_feats
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the trailing commas in your model (VGGBase) and it should be OK.